# how to connect nodes using string similarity instead of exact string match(G.neighbors) in networkx and pandas

Tags: pandas, networkx, graph-theory

```
G1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'Name','State')
G2 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'State','Name')
GT = nx.compose(G1, G2)

print(GT.neighbors(node))
```

how to connect the nodes by similar nodes(string matching) instead of matching identical nodes?

Comment: Check with soundex ?

Comment: checking string similarity is simple using Levehstein distance, the question is how to connect nodes by strings that are similar, e.g.

node: Albert will connect to node :United States.
node: Albert will also connect to node: United State because minimum edit distance is only 1

Answer (score 0):

```
import networkx as nx
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def hot_insert_edge_str_match(G):
    for node in G.nodes():
        for non_neighbor in list(nx.non_neighbors(G,node)):
            if fuzz.ratio(node, non_neighbor) > 90:
                print("string matched", node, non_neighbor)
                G.add_edge(node, non_neighbor)
```

workaround is to manually loop through all nodes and non neighbors and connect them if two strings are matched and above a threshold value